# Socket connection is sometimes deadlocked

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am writing a **server-client** communication using sockets in **python3**. When I run server first time and after that I run client, everything goes well. But when I run it for next time sometimes (not everytime) it do nothing, it looks like server is waiting for a client and vice versa.

Server side:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8098))
serversocket.listen(50) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(1024)
    frc = bytes("I`ve got it", "utf-8")
    connection.send(frc)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf)
        break
connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
connection.close()
```

Client side:

```
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8098))
frc = bytes("Hello I am client", "utf-8")
clientsocket.send(frc)
a=clientsocket.recv(1024)
print(a)
clientsocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
clientsocket.close()
```

Where should be a mistake? Thank you.

Comment: I tested with the break statement commented out and I can't get it to crash on my machine...

Comment: Thank you, it works. But with your solution I am not able to close server connection. Because I want to close it and open again when it will be appropriate.

Comment: Usually in such cases you are sending a special close packet/datagram/(or in your case sequence of bytes). You should have a special sequence such as "THIS IS AN END PACKET, CLOSE THE CONNECTION" or something that you know is not going to ever be sent accidentally. You can't expect to close the connection when the buffer is empty because you'd run into race conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Every time you read something you are are exiting from while (break sentence). Is that the correct behaviour?. After that if you try to connect to the "server" (again) you will be not able to do it. 
Another thing is: if you want to connect more than one client at same time you have to do something like this:

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])         
    #start new thread: 
    #1st argument as a function name to be run
    #2nd is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))
```

I hope it can help.

PS: You have another way to create a TCP server. I suggest you to read this: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socketserver.html